# (Unity) Adding a script to a gameobject when changing layermask

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to be able to add a script to a gameobject when changing its LayerMask. I want this to happen when changing it in the Editor and not in runtime only.

How am I supposed to do this? I am unable to formulate the question on Google to find any neccesary information that might be able to help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am unsure if there is a callback method used by the editor when the LayerMask gets changed. but it is a possibility.  You could also add a custom script that has the attribute `ExecuteInEditMode`  Attach this to every GameObject, and have it check to see if the LayerMask changed, possibly in update, and then add the corresponding script there depending on the LayerMask it changed to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything built-in for that but you could use [GameObject.layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html), store it and compare it.

Using [`[ExecuteInEditMode]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) you can make a omponent execute some methods also in the editor:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class LayerChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int lastLayer;

    // could e.g be a UnityEvent (like onClick of buttons)
    public UnityEvent OnLayerChanged;

    private void Update()
    {
        // if layer didn't change do nothing
        if(lastLayer == gameObject.layer) return;

        // changed! -> what ever you want to happen 
        // e.g. invoke the event or call another method
        OnLayerChanged.Invoke();

        // store the new layer
        lastLayer = gameObject.layer;
    }    
}
```

---

if you want to limit where this happens you can also check for [Application.isEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html) and/or [Application.isPlaying](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isPlaying.html)